# How to get an Erlang port by its ID?

Tags: erlang, erlang-ports

When I have an Erlang process ID, using `pid/3` or `list_to_pid/1` functions (which internally do the same thing) I can get the process for debugging purposes.

```
Process = pid(0,4,1).
Process = list_to_pid("<0.4.1>").
```

So the question is; what about [ports](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/ports.html)?

There are lots of function interfaces which accept both `process()` and `port()` data types, like [`register/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#register-2). So I need to know if there is a way to get ports by their ID (e.g. `#Port<0.567>`) like processes. Is it prohibited? If so, is there any reason for it?

Comment: Good question! It seems a bit wrong that there's a `pid_to_list`, and `list_to_pid`, and also a `port_to_list` but no `list_to_port`. I don't think it can really be prohibited as such though since you can still do `PortAsList = term_to_binary(Port)` and `Port = binary_to_term(PortAsList)`, and it works, and that's functionally the same thing.

Comment: @Michael That will only work if he's got the port reference to start with, which seems to be the problem. I wrote a solution from scratch below -- but the OP should be carefully considering why he thinks this is necessary at all (it could be, just seems odd).

Comment: @zxq9 Hmm, not sure what you mean. `binary_to_term(<<131,102,100,0,13,110,111,110,111,100,101,64,110,111,104,111,115,116,0,0,0,0,0>>)` gives you `#Port<0.0>`, and `binary_to_term(<<131,102,100,0,13,110,111,110,111,100,101,64,110,111,104,111,115,116,15,255,255,255,0>>)` gives you `#Port<0.268435455>`. As far as I can see you could start with a binary, or construct any port, using whatever string to binary conversion you like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything in the standard library to help with this, but there is [the `recon_lib:term_to_port/1` function](https://github.com/ferd/recon/blob/master/src/recon_lib.erl#L157-177) in the [recon library](https://github.com/ferd/recon) that does what you want. For example:

```
1> {ok,L} = gen_tcp:listen(0, []).
{ok,#Port<0.687>}
2> L = recon_lib:term_to_port("#Port<0.687>").
#Port<0.687>
```

This code opens a listen socket on an ephemeral port and stores it in variable `L`. It then asserts, using pattern matching, that the result of passing the stringified port `#Port<0.687>` to `recon_lib:term_to_port/1` returns exactly the same socket as `L`.

Comment: Yes, interesting. I was thinking one could do that (recon_lib:term_to_port uses binary_to_term to convert a constructed binary into a port term) but I wonder what the portability/stability issues might be.

Comment: Yet another interesting function from recon I've never had a need for (yet). :-)

Comment: @Michael: since such a function is just for debugging, I don't think there are any portability/stability issues to worry about.

Comment: @SteveVinoski It uses External Term Format to recreate it which looks smart and I didn't see this function in recon before, so thanks for it. However my second question still remains which is about the reason that standard library lacks such API.

Comment: @HamidrezaSoleimani: I think you'd need someone from the OTP team to answer that.

Answer (score 2):

First off, let's establish this early, you need to understand *why you think you need this functionality*. Maybe you have a good reason -- but this smells an awful lot like an X-Y problem to me.

*[EDIT: I just saw Steve's post using the recon library for this. If you happen to be using recon, that's an awesome way to do it. If not... go learn about recon. It is excellent. The solution below is if you are doing things from scratch.]*

That said, let's see what we can do, since we only have [`erlang:port_to_list/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#port_to_list-1) to work with (that I'm aware of).

Consider something like:

```
-module(porter).
-export([port/2]).

-spec port(non_neg_integer(), non_neg_integer()) -> undefined | port().
port(A, B) ->
    PortString = lists:flatten(io_lib:format("#Port<~w.~w>", [A, B])),
    CheckPort = fun(Z) -> PortString == erlang:port_to_list(Z) end,
    case lists:filter(CheckPort, erlang:ports()) of
        []  -> undefined;
        [P] -> P
    end.
```

And in the shell:

```
1> c(porter).
{ok,porter}
2> erlang:ports().
[#Port<0.0>,#Port<0.318>,#Port<0.328>,#Port<0.337>]
3> porter:port(0, 328).
#Port<0.328>
4> porter:port(0, 400).
undefined
```

This may or may not serve your purpose... but again, consider why you need this. It is probably a lot more sane to add a utility function to your project that keeps track of what ports you actually have open if you need to manipulate them manually.

Comment: My purpose is debugging ports simply; in the same way that I debug processes. Also I considered that using `erlang:ports/0` I can get a list of ports and get the desired one which works, but not as the best way. However thanks for taking time, it lets people to know about what `ports/0` and `port_to_list/1` can do.